# How would the inhabitants of Barovia respond to a satyr?

Tags: dnd-5e, curse-of-strahd

A player has an established character who is a satyr.

These are unheard of in Barovia, so would likely be mistaken for Mongrelfolk.

How would the various inhabitants across Barovia respond to Mongrelfolk or a satyr?

Comment: Related: [How can I make people fear a player with a monstrous character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180893/48793)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We actually see satyrs referenced at least a couple times in Barovia:

The first time it's in the wood paneling that clads the walls of Durst Manor (see *Main Hall* on page 212) and again as a recoverable loot item on page 204.

The reason this imagery can exist is because Barovia has not always been locked away behind the mists and so would have had access to lore from outside the realm/plane.

Of course, that doesn't mean Barovia's inhabitants have actually *seen* (or remember seeing) a real satyr. It's possible, but unlikely.

Page 26 of the campaign book offers this guidance on the section labeled *Barovians and Nonhumans*:

> Barovians thus react to nonhuman characters the same way most humans in the real world would react to elf, dwarf, or half-ore adventurers suddenly walking the streets. Most such outsiders are scorned, feared, or shunned.

And this makes sense: Satyrs have horns and look like weregoats. If you were to draw up a "Nope!" list for Barovians, horns and lycanthropy (tragothropy? I don't know Greek) would be on it.

Of course, the DM is always empowered to find a way to make Barovians more accepting of Satyrs. But, even without any fiddling with the narrative knobs, there *are* people that would most likely be much more accepting of a dionysian figure: the "book club" in Vallaki and the Vistani come immediately to mind.

What narrative hyjinx would ensue if your satyr player could only safely hang out in the open with the Vistani or was immediately and warmly approached by members of the book club?